# Is there integration with Alfresco and OwnCloud?

Tags: deployment, integration, alfresco, owncloud

Is there integration with Alfresco and Own-cloud? Or how to deploy alfresco to own-cloud?

Comment: What kind of integration do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that it is possible to deploy Alfresco to OwnCloud. It also looks like OwnCloud does not (at the time of writing) support CMIS (see https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/17563) so I think that it will be hard if not impossible to create an integration between Alfresco and OwnCloud.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I stopped my investigation in Alfresco these days as I'm busy in some projects. But I will return again when I finish these projects.

Answer (score 0):

But I saw a free web application before called **MultCloud** that can [access all cloud storage in one place](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/access-all-cloud-storage-in-one-place-6289.html). There are more than 20 cloud services supported, including ownCloud and Alfresco.

Once you add your accounts into it, you're able to sync or transfer files among them directly from the web page. I use this tool to manage my Dropbox, Evernote and ownCloud. It would give a help from my point of view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. i will try it.